# Desktop map app with Qt/c++ and openseemap

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, openseamap

I have to write a desktop map application using c++ and openseamap. Right now I am looking for a GUI library for this. I thought I could use qt5 for this, but I can't be sure before the start I must make sure that ı can use qt and openseamap together. Can ıt be possible if not is there any succession for GUI library for use with openseamap

Comment: Qt Location module is related with your question. I looked at it but I didn't see there is a support for OpenSeaMap. I am sharing the link, maybe you could also look at it. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtlocation-index.html#plugin-references-and-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The openseamap just provides map files which are in a format called "MBTiles" which is actually just a SQLite database. There is no problem to use Qt for the GUI and to let such Qt application access a SQLite database. There is also SQLite support for Qt, for instance look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-cachedtable-example.html).

There is also [Qt support for OpenStreetMap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-plugin-osm.html) which is where OpenSeaMap bases on.